# Beautiful Soup - extract intact sentences of text that contain random markup tags

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a page with beautiful soup to extract the title text (denoted by class="view"). However, there are styling tags around some words in the sentence which makes collecting a stack of complete sentences or titles more difficult.

```
<div class="title"><a ref="ordinalpos=2&amp;ncbi_uid=5514220&amp;link_uid=5514220&amp;linksrc=docsum_title" href="/pmc/articles/PMC5514220/" class="view"><b>Sirtuins</b>, a promising target in slowing down the ageing process</a></div>
```

At the moment I'm using a regular expression to match the tags and replace them with an empty string.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/?term=sirtuins"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url))
new_content = []
pattern = re.compile(r'(<b>)|(<\/b>)|(<em>)|(<\/em>)|[^\w ]|(PDF.*)')
for view in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'class':'view'}):
    for item in view.contents:
        new_content.append(re.sub(pattern,'', str(item), flags=0))
```

However, the end product I am left with is a list of broken words from multiple titles.

```
['The Role of ',
 'Sirtuins',
 ' in Antioxidant and Redox Signaling',
 '',
 'Sirtuins',
 ' a promising target in slowing down the ageing process',
 '',
 'The NAD',
 'supsup',
 'Dependent Family of ',
 'Sirtuins',
 ' in Cerebral Ischemia and Preconditioning',
 '',
```

Is there anyway to extract/join/clean this text so I am left with the whole sentence without those tags?

Thank you :)

**Edit:** Expected output:

```
['The Role of Sirtuins in Antioxidant and Redox Signaling',
 'Sirtuins a promising target in slowing down the ageing process',
 'The NAD Dependent Family of Sirtuins in Cerebral Ischemia and Preconditioning']
```

Comment: ya. finish it up with `final_text = ' '.join(new_content)` after your `for` loop

Comment: This joins all the sentences together though as opposed to individual titles

Comment: can you post your expected output as well?

Comment: @skiventist, you're not very clear on what you want. as stated above, post what your expected output would look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you just grab the text in the `div` tags with class=title? The beauty of beautifulsoup is that it understands how tags and markdown works, so to get the text, you don't need to filter out markdown tags.

But as stated, it's hard to understand what you want. I'm just guessing here that you are trying to pull out he titles.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/?term=sirtuins"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url))
new_content = []

for view in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'title'}):
    new_content.append(view.text)
```

**Output:**

```
print (new_content)
['The Role of Sirtuins in Antioxidant and Redox Signaling', 'Sirtuins, a promising target in slowing down the ageing process', 'The NAD+-Dependent Family of Sirtuins in Cerebral Ischemia and Preconditioning', 'Sirtuins and the metabolic hurdles in cancer', 'Mitochondrial Sirtuins and Molecular Mechanisms of Aging', 'Sirtuins in the Cardiovascular System: Potential Targets in Pediatric Cardiology', 'Sirtuins at the crossroads of stemness, aging, and cancer', 'Sirtuins of parasitic protozoa: In search of function(s)', 'Genealogy of an ancient protein family: the Sirtuins, a family of disordered members', 'Sirtuins and Their Roles in Brain Aging and Neurodegenerative Disorders', 'The controversial world of sirtuins', 'Potential Modulation of Sirtuins by Oxidative Stress', 'Sirtuins in Skin and Skin Cancers', 'Schistosoma mansoni Sirtuins: Characterization and Potential as Chemotherapeutic Targets', 'Sirtuins, aging, and cardiovascular risks', 'Controversial Impact of Sirtuins in Chronic Non-Transmissible Diseases and Rehabilitation Medicine', 'Sirtuins Link Inflammation and Metabolism', 'Sirtuins in metabolism, DNA repair and cancer', 'Sirtuins Expression and Their Role in Retinal Diseases', 'Application of Targeted Mass Spectrometry for the Quantification of Sirtuins in the Central Nervous System']
```